# how to remove "disabled" attribute once other input field filled with at least 6 characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 input fields one is enabled and one is disabled, on entering at least 6 characters in enabled field the second one (disabled field) should be enabled using javascript.

Comment: Share your HTML too

Comment: Any research? Any googling at all? Surely you're not the first person ever to ask this.

Comment: What do you have so far? Any code written yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach with an `eventListener`:

```js
document.getElementById('enabled').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (this.value.length >= 6) {
    document.getElementById('disabled').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('disabled').disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="enabled" placeholder="Type here...">
<input type="text" id="disabled" disabled>
```

Comment: yeah or `document.getElementById('second').disabled = this.value.length < 6` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#input1").keydown(function() {
  if($(this).val().length > 6) {
    $("#input2").attr('disabled', false)
  }
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input1" />
  <input type="text" id="input2" disabled /> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you can use the `input` event handler on the first input, then use `prop()` to enable or disable the second input, based on the provided value.

It's possible to use `keyup` or `keydown` event handlers as an alternative, but be aware that they will not work when content is added or removed from the input using the mouse only.

Try this:

```js
$('#enable').on('input', function() {
  $('#disable').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length < 6);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputContainer">
  <input type="text" id="enable" name="online-id" value="" class="focus sprite-clear_input_icns" placeholder="Online ID" />
</div>

<div class="inputContainer">
  <input type="password" id="disable" class="masked" name="passcode" value="" placeholder="Passcode" disabled="true" readonly />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prop` to enable disable your text with `length`.

```js
$("#target1").keyup(function() {
  var len = $('#target1').val().length;
  if (len >= 6)
    $("#target2").prop('disabled', false);
  else
    $("#target2").prop('disabled', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='target1' />
<input type='text' id='target2' disabled/>
```

Comment: `$("#target2").prop('disabled',  e.target.value.length < 6 )`